# Shell_exec is not working!

Tags: raspbian, gpio, php

I have Raspbian os and trying to run GPIO commands from a PHP file. Unfortunately the `shell_exec` is not able to execute any command! 99% I am sure it is a permission issue! I search in Google and read many articles and none of them worked for me. So I install a fresh copy of Raspbian + Apache + PHP. I ran following command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

and then I ran `sudo visudo` and added the following line:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Still no luck. I am tired of this! Can anybody tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

check your `php.ini` and search for the line `disable_functions`

example:

```
disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,and more functions...
```

See if there is `shell_exec` in the list and remove it. Then, restart your webserver and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've tried on a fresh install (and `shell_exec()` is usually enabled by default), it points to the actual `shell_exec()` command.  Might be a silly question, but are you prefixing the command with `sudo`?

Also, you will get a permission error if you're trying to directly execute a script (e.g. `./script.py`, as opposed to `python script.py`) which doesn't have the execute permission, regardless of if you're running as root or not. You can fix this with a `chmod +x script.py`

---

On a related note, I'd also suggest looking at some native php libraries that don't require sudo for basic GPIO.  I'm aware of a couple that take advantage of `gpiomem`.  This is better for many reasons.

You could try [PHPi](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi) or [PiPHP](https://github.com/PiPHP/GPIO) - both are in active development.

*disclaimer: I am involved with the above projects.*